# How to do a better nil check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm getting the following error: 'undefined method `active?' for nil:NilClass'

when I try call

```
@user.subscription.active?
```

because sometimes the subscription has not been created yet. I then wrote a method to check if the user had an existing active subscription:

```
  def active_subscription?
    if !self.subscription.nil?
      if self.subscription.active?
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Is there a better way to write this active_subscription? method without all the if else checks and or return statements?

Here is the method in the subscription model checking if the subscription status is active

```
def active?
 status == 'active'
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be ok:

```
def active_subscription?
  subscription && subscription.active?
end
```

or even shorter:

```
def active_subscription?
  subscription.try(:active?)
end
```

to ensure the only values this method can return are `true` and `false`, you can:

```
def active_subscription?
  !!subscription.try(:active?)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that 'subscription && subscription.active?' wouldn't get to the .active? check if the first part (ie subscription) was nil

Comment: @spuggy it happens so because it's unnecessary to check second condition if the first condition of AND logical statement is false (or "falsy").

Comment: @spuggy this is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: In order for the whole expression `x && y` to be true, both `x` and `y` must individually be true. If `x` is `false` or `nil`, there's no need to evaluate `y` because it's impossible for the whole expression to be true. You can take advantage of short-circuit evaluation any time you need to call a method on an object that may or may not exist at the time the method is called. Just make sure you put the `nil` test first to avoid the exception that would be raised by the method call. By the way, you should accept Marek's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription
  delegate :active?, to: :subscription, prefix: :subscription, allow_nil: true
  # ...
end
```

Now you can call

```
user.subscription_active?
```

It returns `subscription.active?` (i.e. `true` or `false`) if the subscription is available and `nil` if the association is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
def active_subscription?
  subscription && subscription.active?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With safe navigation you can use `@user.subscription&.active`

It checks for nil before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@user.subscription.active? if @user.subscription.present?
```

Comment: The answer is not wrong its just that it does'nt make any sense to you. Please use your right to vote down wisely.